# How to communicate to HC 06 Bluetooth with Nucleo ST F410RE

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, mbed

I have a HC06 bluetooth module and recently I got my Nucleo ST F401RE arduino compatible mbed board. I want to have a communication between Nucleo board and HC06 bluetooth module. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what Nucleo board you use? F401RE or F411RE
Basically, HC06 is controlled through UART communication.
First step you have to do is connecting UART pins between HC06 and Nucleo.

```
UART pin connection:
HC06 GND -- Nucleo GND
HC06 TX  -- Nucleo RX
HC06 RX  -- Nucleo TX
```

For Necleo side, you can use UART1 freely.
You cannot use UART2(D0, D1) because it is shared with USB serial.
[image: See Nucleo pin map.]

```
UART1 RX pin: D2
UART1 TX pin: D10
```

You can create instance of Serial class like following.

```cpp
Serial uart1(D10 /* TX */, D2 /* RX */);
```

Beware of voltage difference between HC06 and Nucleo.
The core voltage of Nucleo is 3.3.